# Tomcat in Production

Tags: java, tomcat, cluster-computing, production

What's the best way to achieve central management of a cluster of Tomcat servers in production? Specifically, I'm looking for automatic application (WAR) deployment, consolidated logs, and basic health monitoring at a minimum. What open source or commercial management tools are people using for this?

Comment: Wouldn't serverfault fit this question better?

Comment: True. Should've thought of that.

Answer (score 2):

[LambdaProbe](http://www.lambdaprobe.org/d/index.htm) is a commonly used open source solution.

you can get Cluster health monitoring and App deployment, see the [screenshots](http://www.lambdaprobe.org/d/screenshots.shtml) and in particular http://www.lambdaprobe.org/d/screenshots/full/cluster.png

and http://www.lambdaprobe.org/d/screenshots/full/deployment.png

You get [logging](http://www.lambdaprobe.org/d/screenshots/full/logs.png) as well, I'm not sure about the consolidated log for the cluster though.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the  [(VMWare) Spring Source portfolio](http://www.springsource.com), especially:

- tc Server (commercial version of
  Tomcat)
- Hyperic

AFAIK some of the key people of Apache Tomcat are Spring Source engineers.